# How to fix the erratic font sizing behavior of iOS Safari?

Tags: html, css, ios, fonts, safari

**Safari** on iOS (I use iOS 13, newest version) has some kind of automatic font sizing behavior that, if necessary, enlarges fonts to make them easily readable on an iPhone. Basically this is an alternative for a responsive layout if your layout is simple and flexible enough to allow for different font sizes.

Many people don’t like this behavior, and when you’re googling it, you’ll mostly get recipes how to prevent it.

But I do like this behavior and want to use it for a simple web site mostly consisting of text.

The problem is that **Safari** does not treat *all* text this way, and it is (to me at least) completely unclear what this behavior depends on.

So if, for instance, you have body text in 14px and want to have some text in a larger font size (headings, whatever …), say 18px, it *might* happen that **Safari** enlarges the 14px text, but not the 18px text. The result is that the text that is supposed to be larger than the body text is in fact smaller, which of course destroys the whole layout. Changing the font *sometimes* seems to have the same unintended effect. As I said, it seems to be completely erratic when **Safari** does this and when it doesn’t. I’ve been fighting with this for over a week now, and it almost drove me crazy.

Here is a simple example (but please note that you will see the issue only if you put this on a web server and watch it in **Safari** on iOS).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Size Test</title>

    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: serif;
        }

        .Head {
            color: red;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
       eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
       voluptua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
       nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed
       diam voluptua.</p>
    <p class="Head">Foo Bar</p>
    <!-- <p class="Head">Foo Bar</p> -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
       eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
       voluptua.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I have a headline class that only changes the font type (the red color is just for pointing out the problem). This is enough to make **Safari** on iOS ignore it when enlarging fonts; i.e. although the font size should not change, in fact the *Foo Bar* line is much smaller than the rest of the text.

However, this changes as soon as you use this class at least *twice*. So if you uncomment the second *Foo Bar* line in the code example, suddenly *both* lines will be displayed in the correct font size in **Safari** on iOS. Of course, this behavior is completely nonsensical. In case I need this class only once, I cannot use it twice just to make **Safari** display it correctly.

After seemingly endless trial and error, I found a workaround: **Safari** on iOS will always display the font size correctly if the paragraph includes at least 1 `<br>` tag and at least 1 character after it. (Again, this makes no sense at all …)

So, if you use `<p class="Head">Foo Bar<br>&nbsp;</p>` and then set the bottom margin of the **.Head** class to a large enough negative value to compensate for the unintended second line, it does work – **Safari** on iOS will always display the enlarged font size, even if the class is used only once (at least it did in my tests).

But of course, this is an *extremely* ugly workaround.

So, my question basically is if someone knows of a less ugly workaround that is as reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This reply is a bit late, but try adding the following to your head and then tweaking your font sizes accordingly.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

I have attached three images. The first one is your code, with the small font size on the header, the second one is your code with the comment part removed (i.e. the version that works) and the third is with the viewport.

[image: Screenshot of Erratic Font - Per Q]

[image: Screenshot of Correct Fonts - Per Q]

[image: Screenshot of Suggested Approach - Per Answer]

More reading (when you said the word erratic, this came to mind first):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Now that is interesting, thank you! Unfortunately, it has some side effects (some other fonts are now suddenly bigger than expected), and most of all, I need to use a fixed width instead of ``device-width`` in my actual code (in which case your suggestion does not seem to work anymore), but this could point in the right direction. I will investigate further and report here if the right ``viewport`` settings could fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm just learning, but as I understand, it is standard practice to put the above line in all your files. I think the line is pretty standard, perhaps play around with the rest of CSS and maybe rethink how you approach the design. The font size will be driven by the defaults, but you might be able to fix this by doing something like html { font-size: 14px }. Then you can define the rest of the fonts in terms of "em". However, I'm not sure, I know it works for fixed percentages, e.g. font-size: 80% (which will be 80% of the device default).

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me.
My solution : use padding instead of margin !
Works great !

Comment: Hi Yves, welcome to Stack Overflow. You answer may be correct but it is currently not very helpful. It would become a great answer if you provided some context for you solution (code examples or links to documentation). See this link for help on writing great answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Good luck